# fragmenttabhost, can't remove gap between tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, tabwidget

I need change indicator border line for my tabs, so i do following:

```
           //set custom background for each tab
View v;
            int count = tabWidget.getTabCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                v = tabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(i);
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector_main);
                v.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                params.setMargins(-Utils.dpToPx(3, this), 0, -Utils.dpToPx(3, this), 0);
            }
```

here is my drawable, in which i set 9-patches

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_green" />

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_unpressed_green" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_unpressed"/>
</selector>
```

The problem is, that after that, the default divider is gone, and there are some gap between tabs. How can i enable default divider or set mine? I google a lot, and seems nothing help me. I use 4.0.4 version and fragmenttabhost with tabwidget. Thanks.
[image]

**UPD:** I found what problem is in my 9-patches. I change color to transparent, except bottom indicator line and setDividerDrawable start working. but still there are gap between bottom indicator line.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the solution , it would even be better to answer in details and accept your answer .

Answer (score 2):

You can use android:showDividers="none" in your XML layout.

```
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:showDividers="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        android:divider="@null" <-Works like a charm
```